# Wordpress wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script not working

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I was following a wp theme developement tutorial but somehow my wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script not working
here is my code

functions.php

```
<?php
//Adding the css and js files
function gt_setup(){
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Slab');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome','https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri());
    // wp_enqueue_script($handle,$src,$deps,$ver,$in_footer);
    wp_enqueue_script('main',get_theme_file_uri('/js/main.js'),NULL,'1.0',true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script','gt_setup');
?>
```

i have added  within head in header.php and  before body in footer.php

here is my style.css

```
/*
Theme Name:GTCoding
Author:Godson Thomas
Author URI:www.google.com
Description:Test theme
Version:1.0
*/

body{
    background:red;
}
```

js/main.js

```
alert ("hello from main.js");
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>GTCoding</title>
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Header here</h1>
  </header>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>
 <p>Footer was here</p>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header();?>

<h2>Hi from index.php</h2>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

i am stuck with this for days..please help
i searched the forum but i think my problem is specific..please dont mark this duplicate

Comment: thats exactly what i did..the first block of php code that i pasted is from functions.php

Comment: what is the html output of the site in the browser? how did you establish the fact that the code  'is not working'? why do you link the same styles directly in header.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action is `wp_enqueue_script` and not `wp_enqueue_scripts`. This should fix it. Lemme know how it goes! :)

```
<?php
//Adding the css and js files
function gt_setup(){
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Slab');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome','https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri());
    // wp_enqueue_script($handle,$src,$deps,$ver,$in_footer);
    wp_enqueue_script('main',get_theme_file_uri('/js/main.js'),NULL,'1.0',true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','gt_setup');
?>
```

Comment: thanks..that worked..cheers!

Comment: Glad I could be of help! :)